# Image size for ActionBarSherlock background

Tags: android, image, png, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

If I were to get an art asset made intended for use as the background of an ActionBar, what size (in pixels) should I request?  Everything I have found referencing the size of an ActionBar has been in dp, so I'm unsure what would be the best absolute size to go with for the actual .png file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action bar can be 40, 48, or 56 dp in height depending on configuration. This means that because of how Android scales things by density there are 9 different absolute pixel heights. The width varies depending on the device, of course.

Your best bet is to use [9-patch drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) or create the drawable using a [shape XML](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) so that it can adapt to the nearly infinite number of configurations of devices.