# Creating an image for ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to create an image to put in the ActionBar. I know how to set the image to be the background, I'm just not sure on how to create the image. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11371395/1393498) it seems that I should do a 9-patch drawable and [this web application](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) seems to allow me to create one from an image.

What I need to know is what kind of image should I use to create the 9-patch drawable for an ActionBar?

- Does the image resolution matter?
- Does the format matter?
- Does the 'physical' size of the image (KB) matter?

When creating a 9-patch drawable using the web app I mentioned, it outputs four different images, a xxhdpi, xdpi, hdpi and mdpi. Depending on the size of the image that I uploaded and the density I specify, these images change in size (resolution).

How do I know that I have the correct image size for each screen density? Obviously the images must be resized to fit the screen of the device, so if the image needs to be enlarged, this will lead to distortion. Is it thus, better practice to ensure the images are always larger than they need to be, to make sure they are are not distorted? Because that seems like a waste to me. Or does this matter less than I think it does?

Any tutorials on how to make 9-patch's or ActionBar background images would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** - Resolution matters if you want to support different screen densities.
**2** - A 9 patch is a **png**, so format matters.
**3** - The weight of the image affects the overall apk size.
Try to be `moderate` (consider that the height of your image shouldn't be taller than your ActionBar's height - or it's just wasted junk bytes).
Bear in mind that you want to use a 9 patch in order to stretch a content, so to minimize the KB weight impact.

**4** - You can also use a plain png, instead of a .9.png. In this case, be mindful and try to minimize the size of your bitmap (you can use opti-png or similar tools, to squeeze out useless information of your png files)

Comment: Is there a good tutorial/application that will show me how to do this the right way?

Comment: Define `this`: A 9-patch? here's a very nice tutorial: http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/ or Opti-PNG? It's on the site documentation page.

Comment: Yes a 9-patch. Specifically a 9-patch for an ActionBar, but a basic 9-patch tutorial will do the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: There's no ActionBar-specific 9 patch. Just keep in mind the proportions (don't make it higher than 96px for xxhdpi, 64 for xhdpi, 48 for hdpi, 32 for mdpi, 24 for ldpi). I woul make no sense make it higher. for the width, keep in mind the minimum width (portait width) of the screen and don't make the patch wider.

Comment: That's great thanks. The upper bounds really help :)